# Making dynamic straw poll

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to make something like http://strawpoll.me/ for learning purposes.
User creates a poll, so a poll can hold options as much as he wants to.

I think this shouldnt be a problem but I'm not sure how to set up polls in database.
Is every poll creating a table for itself?
Or are polls in the same table but are inserted by row with id? In that case I'm not sure how would i need to set up columns..

I need a hint to get me moving :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polls themselves are inside the table `poll`. There is another table called `poll_option`. Let's assume we have the following poll:

- Name: Poll 1
- Option 1: This is poll 1
- Option 2: This is NOT poll 5

In `poll`, there'd be:

`id`, `poll_name`, `date_created` for example. `poll_option` would then contain `id`, `option_name`, `poll_id`. `poll_id` would be the poll this option is a part of.

There would of course be the need for voting, so a third table is needed: `poll_votes`. `poll_vote` merely contain `id`, `date_created` and `user_id`. `user_id` is either the IP, a cookie, or a session key of the user. Straw Poll saves a cookie called `uid` as to identify if you have already voted in this poll.

Putting it all together:

```
TABLE: poll
id | poll_name | date_created
62 | Poll 1    | 2014-01-11 12:34:56

TABLE: poll_option
id  | option_name        | poll_id
844 | This is poll 1     | 62
844 | This is NOT poll 5 | 62

TABLE: poll_vote
id   | user_id | date_created
1104 | 482424  | 2014-01-12 13:53:55
```